# Firebase set does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web, firebase

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    var config = {
        apiKey : "AIzaSyCnmZWNwp3CfjXDcDL5MADIej6GwvxWEtQ",
        authDomain : "dsmweb-ba185.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL : "https://dsmweb-ba185.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket : "dsmweb-ba185.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var usersRef = ref.child("assignment");
    userRef.set(<%=submit%>);
</script>
```

This is my code .. And That does not work.
submit variable is mean

```
{Testuser={date=8/8, teachername=Testuser, title=Let's do homework}}
```

Comment: Can you check the console, for any firebase error ?

Comment: I already Check the console, but there is no error

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One thing immediately jumping out is that your page doesn't define `ref`.